# Number of arguments in python

Tags: python, random

I have problem with this code

```
import random

class MyPlayer:

 def __init__(self, payoff_matrix, number_of_iterations=0):
    self.payoff_matrix = payoff_matrix
    self.number_of_iterations = number_of_iterations
    self.opponent_move = None
    self.opponent_move_history = list()


 def move(self): #move is random, True or False
    return random.choice(False, True)

 def record_opponents_move(self, opponent_move): #recording opponents moves
    self.opponent_move = opponent_move
    self.opponent_move_history.append(opponent_move)
```

Pycharm is still showing a TypeError: choice() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given), I dont get it True and False are just 2 arguments? Or not?

Answer (score 4):

Your `random.choice()` call should be like:

```
>>> import random
>>> random.choice([False, True]) # wrapped within list
True
```

Now coming to the issue. As per the [random.choice()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) document, it receives only one parameter as *sequence*. But in the error you see *takes exactly 2 arguments* because `choice()` function is defined in `Random` class ([source code](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/tags/r32/Lib/random.py)). The class methods expects the first argument (also known as `self`) to function as the object of the same class. So here, `random` is passed as `self`.

Please also read [What is the purpose of self in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-self-in-python) for more clarity on this.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out. You are right, of course, that was the problem.

Comment: @JozefSkála: No need of thanks. If the answer helped you, please mark [it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

`random.choice` takes an iterable, not separate arguments.

```
random.choice([True, False])
```

Comment: Might be worth pointing out the "third" argument in the OP's example is `random` itself